# Using if statement to count rows

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, vba

I was wondering if it is possible to use an if else statement when you are counting rows. So I am importing data from one workbook to another. If the cell in column U is empty, it will not import it but go to the next one.
However, the total count of imported rows is still counting the skipped one, since it is counting from the selected area.
So is it possible to exclude the ones that might have an empty cell in column U?

Happy Easter

```
For Each c In valg.Cells
   If wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("U" & c.Row) <> "" Then

      ' Macro runs here

   Else
      MsgBox wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("H" & c.Row) & " must have an MDS ID" & vbNewLine & "Skipping this supplier and continue the import", vbCritical, "Error"
     'Exit Sub
   End If
Next

    ' Find the number of rows that is copied over
    wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Activate
    areaCount = Selection.Areas.Count
    If areaCount <= 1 Then
         MsgBox "The selection contains " & Selection.Rows.Count & " suppliers."
         ' Write it in A10 in CIF LISTEN
         wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & Selection.Rows.Count & " Suppliers Added"
    Else
        i = 1
        For Each A In Selection.Areas
            'MsgBox "Area " & I & " of the selection contains " & _
                a.Rows.count & " rows."
            i = i + 1
            rwCount = rwCount + A.Rows.Count
        Next A
        MsgBox "The selection contains " & rwCount & " suppliers."
        ' Write it in A10 in CIF LISTEN
        wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & rwCount & " Suppliers Added"
    End If
```

Comment: It's a little tough to tell the relationship between the rows in `valg.Cells` and `wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("U":U")` but how about an `Application.CountA(wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("U":U"))` or `Application.CountIf(wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("U":U"), "<>")` to return a count of the non-blank cells in U:U that were actually copied over?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through your source data once to copy rows, then again to count what you copied, why don't you just count them as you go through the first time?

I presume that `'Macro runs here` is the location of your copy code, either pass in a `CopiedCount` parameter (preset to 0) that gets updated by the called routine, or change it to a function that returns the `CopiedCount`, or simply increment a counter in that portion of the `IF` statement.

Something like this:

```
Dim CopiedCount as Integer

For Each c In valg.Cells
  If wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("U" & c.Row) <> "" Then
    ' Macro runs here
    CopiedCount = CopiedCount + 1
  Else
    MsgBox wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("H" & c.Row) & " must have an MDS ID" & _
      vbNewLine & "Skipping this supplier and continue the import", _
      vbCritical, "Error"
    'Exit Sub
  End If
Next
MsgBox "There were " & CopiedCount & " suppliers transferred."
```

As I'm reading your code, you could then get rid of everything after that loop.